# Can't get Svelte page to appear

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I'm fairly new to Svelte. I can't get my login page to appear as part of a single page applicaition.

I copied and adapted the example at [Hello world](https://svelte.dev/repl/11e51e1ce65449c0b0db1af0906e206a?version=3.4.4)

But when I click on the link I don't see the page of the HTML from my Login component. The link from the main (index?) page is:

```
http://localhost:5000/#/Login/
```

The code in my App.svelte file is:

```
<script>
    import Login from './Login.svelte';

    const routes = {
      '/Login/': Login
    }
</script>

<body>
  <a href="#/Login/">Login Please!</a>
</body>
```

The code in my Login script (in the root directory of the project) is:

```
<script>
  let user;
  const unUser = User.subscribe(v => user = v);
  onDestroy(unUser);
  $: isLoggedIn = !!user;
</script>

<TopNavBar/>
{#if isLoggedIn}
  <p>Already Logged In</p>
{:else}
  let email, password;
  email = '';
  password = '';

  <h1 class="dscript">Login to Foobar</h1>
  <form>
    ...
```

Comment: Are you using `svelte-spa-router`?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not. I guess you're suggesting it. I'm wondering why there are various routers etc. What's wrong with the built in one?

Comment: Svelte alone doesn't come with a router, the example you in the REPL uses the svelte-spa-router. check this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/787dd12d87024c6aa6d55aceb2f6943f?version=3.37.0).

Comment: @ShrijiKondan Thanks for info. How does that compare with Webpack?

Comment: webpack and rollup are bundlers, they aren't routers, I personally prefer rollup.